# Magento salerule really slow query 2 minutes to execute

Tags: cart, sales-order

We run Magento with many sales rules as each user has a referral promo code that he can share with his friends. However this impact the performance of our magento server as it is really slow when customer create a cart or add item to cart.

We have New relic setup which gave us insight why our magento is slow.

New relic has pointed us that this query is taking an average 2 minutes to execute. In high load.

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, NULL AS `code` FROM `salesrule` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `salesrule_website`.`rule_id` FROM `salesrule_website` WHERE (website_id IN (?))) AS `website` ON main_table.rule_id = website.rule_id INNER JOIN `salesrule_customer_group` AS `customer_group_ids` ON main_table.rule_id = customer_group_ids.rule_id AND customer_group_ids.customer_group_id = ? WHERE (from_date is null or from_date <= ?) AND (to_date is null or to_date >= ?) AND (`is_active` = ?) AND (main_table.coupon_type = ?) AND (`is_active` = ?) ORDER BY sort_order ASC
```

and this one

```
SELECT `t`.* FROM (SELECT `main_table`.*, NULL AS `code` FROM `salesrule` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `salesrule_website`.`rule_id` FROM `salesrule_website` WHERE (website_id IN (?))) AS `website` ON main_table.rule_id = website.rule_id INNER JOIN `salesrule_customer_group` AS `customer_group_ids` ON main_table.rule_id = customer_group_ids.rule_id AND customer_group_ids.customer_group_id = ? WHERE (from_date is null or from_date <= ?) AND (to_date is null or to_date >= ?) AND (`is_active` = ?) AND (main_table.coupon_type = ?) UNION ALL SELECT `main_table`.*, `rule_coupons`.`code` FROM `salesrule` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `salesrule_website`.`rule_id` FROM `salesrule_website` WHERE (website_id IN (?))) AS `website` ON main_table.rule_id = website.rule_id INNER JOIN `salesrule_customer_group` AS `customer_group_ids` ON main_table.rule_id = customer_group_ids.rule_id AND customer_group_ids.customer_group_id = ? INNER JOIN `salesrule_coupon` AS `rule_coupons` ON main_table.rule_id = rule_coupons.rule_id AND main_table.coupon_type <> ? AND rule_coupons.code = ? WHERE (from_date is null or from_date <= ?) AND (to_date is null or to_date >= ?) AND (`is_active` = ?) AND (main_table.coupon_type = ? AND rule_coupons.type = ? OR (main_table.coupon_type = ?) AND ((main_table.use_auto_generation = ? AND rule_coupons.type = ?) OR (main_table.use_auto_generation = ? AND rule_coupons.type = ?)))) AS `t` WHERE (`is_active` = ?) ORDER BY sort_order ASC
```

can you please advice on how to optimize Magento regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you add something to the cart, all active salesrules are checked in order to see which apply to your new cart configuration. It becomes intuitive enough that by having multiple rules set as active, would mean a larger volume of data to process and check (and this happens even if the rules don't actually apply to your current cart). Add concurrency and there you have it :)

Therefore, as a piece of advice, I would suggest that you keep the number of sales rules that are set as active to a minimum.

This also means that it's probably the time to rethink the referral mechanism and make sure that the is probably only one / a small set of rules active and that the coupon codes are generated and shared from.

Comment: Thank you @Diana but how can we fix this temporary as changing the mechanism will take take

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a full solution. It's better to rethink the referral mechanism and reduce the active cart rules number.